# How to know which of two hosting companies would give me better TTFB?

Tags: webserver, shared-hosting, ttfb

I have a website with a principally all core MediaWiki (no added CSS/JS, no backend customizations, no addons) which is also imageless (there are no images); Webpages are generally only text of up to 10,000 bytes each and website is very new (less than two months on the web).

I have the problem of experiencing tremendously slow Time to first byte (TTFB) with my current PaaS-modeled (shared) hosting plan; the problem persist with or without maximal caching, with or without CloudFlare, and with or without both. The support team has no solution for this besides offering me better and yet much more expansive plans.

I can solve my problems by migrating my website from my current shared hosting provider to one of two shared hosting providers which are more "MediaWiki-friendly" and I guess that from both of them I would have chosen the one which gives me much better TTFBs so thus I ask how to know which of two hosting companies would give me better TTFB (if it's at all possible without buying service)?

Comment: You can often get a free trial at a hosting company to test things like this out.  Do either of these companies offer a free trial?

Comment: It may not be an issue with your host. Did you make sure connections to the website are not bypassing Cloudflare because of dynamic content or some other reason? For the best TTFB, I agree that you should test it for yourself (depending on the cost for the most basic service). You can even get $50 free credit at Vultr right now (I did this a week ago to try it) and $100 free credit at DigitalOcean, which I haven't tried. These offers should appear in the Google ads when you search either one. You'll be responsible for all server setup/connectivity issues with these hosts.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I tend to avoid all the "free trails" with giving credits / money back guarantees but yeah, I understand your point, it might be the only thing besides betting.

Comment: @Trich Thanks, `Did you make sure connections to the website are not bypassing Cloudflare because of dynamic content or some other reason?` I am not sure if I know how to test that but if I understand correctly it's unlikely as the hosting control panel is very straightforward (not even nameservers re-configuration is needed for CloudFlare there); all default with Railgun, etc, no errors appear and MediaWiki is by itself a very "backendish" program.

Comment: Is the existing hosting backed by HDD or SSD?  Its probably not possible to deduce which provider will be better unless you know the server specs and how heavily they load their servers. I dont think its relevant here, but all else being equal you can use ping and puck the one with the lower latency.  (this would only make a small difference though, but its the easiest metric to measure)

Comment: @Semo - You can test that by looking at the response headers using dev tools in your browser (or other ways). If you have Chrome/Brave, open developer tools > network tab, then visit the URL to test. You can see timing, response headers, etc. Make sure it's not responding with "cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC" which means it has to be retrieved from your origin server (much longer TTFB).